# imgur api - get user account statistics

Tags: api, statistics, imgur

Using the Imgur API, Is it possible to get User account statistics? For example -

- Total Number of user accounts
- No. of user accounts created on a given day etc.

I was unable to find an appropriate method in the official Imgur python library for these.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's limited to what you can do as a user.

> Imgur's API exposes the entire Imgur infrastructure via a standardized programmatic interface. Using Imgur's API, you can do just about anything you can do on imgur.com, while using your programming language of choice.
>   - https://api.imgur.com/